# Increase efficiency of component-based game engine

Tags: c++, performance, unordered-map

I'm attempting to build a component based game engine, and my efficiency is definitely lacking. The problem is most noted in my collision detection, because I compare each GameObject against each other GameObject to see if they collide. Here is the collision detection function:

```
void PhysicsSystem::update(float dt) {
std::vector<GameEngine::GameObject> moveObjects = manager->getAllObjectsWithComponent("move");
std::vector<GameEngine::GameObject> physicsObjects = manager->getAllObjectsWithComponent("physics");

for (int i = 0; i < moveObjects.size(); i++) {
    MoveComponent* mComponent = static_cast<MoveComponent*>(manager->getComponentByType("move", moveObjects[i]));
    PhysicsComponent* pComponent = static_cast<PhysicsComponent*>(manager->getComponentByType("physics", moveObjects[i]));
    RenderComponent* rComponent = static_cast<RenderComponent*>(manager->getComponentByType("render", moveObjects[i]));

    if (pComponent == nullptr || mComponent == nullptr || rComponent == nullptr) {
        continue;
    }

    if (!pComponent->isSolid()) {
        continue;
    }

    glm::vec4 coords1 = rComponent->getRenderCoords();


    for (int j = 0; j < physicsObjects.size(); j++) {
        PhysicsComponent* pComponent2 = static_cast<PhysicsComponent*>(manager->getComponentByType("physics", physicsObjects[j]));
        RenderComponent* rComponent2 = static_cast<RenderComponent*>(manager->getComponentByType("render", physicsObjects[j]));
        if (pComponent2 == nullptr || rComponent2 == nullptr) {
            continue;
        }

        if (!pComponent2->isSolid()) {
            continue;
        }


        glm::vec4 coords2 = rComponent2->getRenderCoords();



        int dist = sqrt(pow((coords1.x - coords2.x), 2) + pow((coords1.y - coords2.y), 2));
        if (dist > pComponent->getCollisionRadius()) {
            continue;
        }

        if (GameEngine::Physics::checkCollision(coords1, coords2)) {
            pComponent->addCollision(coords2);
        }
    }
}
```

I tried to increase efficiency by ignoring GameObjects that weren't close to the current GameObject, using the collision radius, but that didn't seem to do anything, the lines of code that really cause issue are

```
PhysicsComponent* pComponent2 = static_cast<PhysicsComponent*>(manager->getComponentByType("physics", physicsObjects[j]));
RenderComponent* rComponent2 = static_cast<RenderComponent*>(manager->getComponentByType("render", physicsObjects[j]));
```

These call a function in my GameObjectManager class. Here's the code for that function:

```
Component* GameObjectManager::getComponentByType(std::string type, GameObject object) {
    std::unordered_map<std::string, std::unordered_map<GLuint, Component*>>::iterator it = componentsByType.find(type);
    if (it == componentsByType.end()) {
        return nullptr;
    }
    std::unordered_map<GLuint, Component*>::iterator it2 = it->second.find(object.getGameObjectID());
    if (it2 == it->second.end()) {
        return nullptr;
    }

    return it2->second;
}
```

If I take out those two lines, the game speeds up significantly. Is there anything that I'm doing wrong? I thought finding an object in an unordered_map was a constant time operation, so I'm not sure how to increase speed. Is there a more efficient way to handle my Components? Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Are you using an optimized / release build?

Comment: Usually you don't iterate over objects but over the components. In your case probably physics components. That would save you one search. I've seen ECS implemented with vectors of components, not hashmaps, but that would require rewritting larger part of your codebase.

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of places here where I see small improvements, although some of them may result in relatively large improvements.  You're making a lot of copies of potentially large data that you don't need to make.

1. `moveObjects` and `physicsObjects` are vectors, and are copies of the original data.  Do these need to be copies, or can they be `const &` the the vectors stored in the game manager?
2. You have several checks with `pComponent`, `mComponent`, and `rComponent`.  If any check fails, you continue to the next object.  Get one of these values, check it for `nullptr`, then  get the next one.  Do `pComponent` first, and check if it is solid, before the other two.
3. Do the same thing with the `j` loop for `pComponent2` and `rComponent2`.
4. When checking the distance, don't compute the square root.  Compare the square of the distance instead.
5. Pass the `object` parameter to `getComponentByType` by `const &` so you don't make a copy of it.  You're only accessing one field of it.
6. Use range-based for loops.  If that is not possible, consider storing the size of your vectors in a variable, rather than calling `size` every loop iteration.  The compiler may optimize the redundant calls out, but the only way to know for sure is to check the generated optimized code.

Comment: 7. Re-think `GameObjectManager::getComponentByType`: `const auto& moveMap = componentsByType.at("move"); const auto& physicMap = componentsByType.at("physics");` would avoid lot of look up/hash.

Comment: These were very helpful tips, and I saw a jump in my FPS, especially after implementing #2. It's still not as fast as I'd like it to be, but these were some really smart fixes, and definitely got me thinking on the right track, thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You query the components in the inner loop for `moveObjects.size()` times, which means a lot of redundant work.

You should put a preprocess loop before the main loop, which collects the components:

```
for (int j = 0; j < physicsObjects.size(); j++) {
    PhysicsComponent* pComponent2 = static_cast<PhysicsComponent*>(manager->getComponentByType("physics", physicsObjects[j]));
    RenderComponent* rComponent2 = static_cast<RenderComponent*>(manager->getComponentByType("render", physicsObjects[j]));
    if (pComponent2 == nullptr || rComponent2 == nullptr) {
        continue;
    }

    if (!pComponent2->isSolid()) {
        continue;
    }

    // add pComponent2 and rComponent2 into an array here
}
```

And then, in the inner loop, use the collected data, instead of querying it from the manager.

Note, that if you have a lot of objects, you may want to put them into some space partitioning data structure (octree/Kd-tree/BSP-tree) to avoid `O(n^2)` running time.